# More elegant method of sorting a file after the first X lines?

Tags: bash, sorting

I've been doing a lot of searching on Stack Overflow today for a solution for this and have found many questions about sorting after skipping X lines, but no really solid generic answers, so I threw together my own slipshod method of doing so:

```
head -n 15 FILE.EXT > temp.txt
tail -n+16 FILE.EXT | sort >> temp.txt
mv temp.txt FILE.EXT
```

This will sort the file (take your pick of the options for sort), while preserving the order of the first 15 lines of it. This is obviously fairly inelegant, with three file references and two different values to enter. Ideally I'd like to come up with a command that is less cumbersome, if possible, because this seems like a pretty common desire with not much support.

- Does anyone have a simpler solution than mine?
- Is there anything wrong with what I've done? Potential issues?
- This problem lends itself more strongly to using a script, but my command is still probably slightly more quick than creating and executing a script for a one-off.

I'm not even close to a bash expert, so I'm hoping there is some bash-fu that can make this a quick one-liner. Is there a way to create and reference variables in a single command so that a user only needs to put in something like the name and line number?

Comment: You probably need to make provision for cleaning up the `temp.txt` if the script is interrupted (signalled).  You also probably need to use a per-process intermediate file name (`mktemp` command, or `temp.$$.txt` at minimum).  You might want to ignore interrupts (signals) while doing the move.

Comment: Better to use a mktemp-based random name than a PID-based one -- if this were in a directory with +t, the PID approach allows another user to easily create, say, a symlink to an arbitrary file they'd like to be overwritten.

Comment: (using a hardcoded `temp.txt` name is, of course, even more dangerous than a PID-based name against symlink attacks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This 'one-liner' generates the output:

```
awk 'NR <= 15 { print; next } { print | "sort" }'
```

Overwriting the original file cleanly is harder, and generally involves something that writes to a temporary file and renames it when that's complete.

As [sputnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465183/sputnick) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789885/more-elegant-method-of-sorting-a-file-after-the-first-x-lines/27790010#comment43990011_27790010), if you have GNU `awk`, you can use the `-i` option to overwrite in-place:

```
gawk -i 'NR <= 15 { print; next } { print | "sort" }' FILE.EXT
```

(And `gawk` is often also installed as `awk`.)

If you don't have GNU `awk`, then I have a script `ow` derived from a script `overwrite` from Kernighan & Pike [The UNIX Programming Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013937681X) that does just that.

Usage:

```
ow FILE.EXT awk 'NR <= 15 { print; next } { print | "sort" }' FILE.EXT
```

Code:

```
:   "@(#)$Id: ow.sh,v 1.6 2005/06/30 18:14:08 jleffler Exp $"
#
#   Overwrite file
#   From: The UNIX Programming Environment by Kernighan and Pike
#   Amended: remove PATH setting; handle file names with blanks.

case $# in
0|1)    
    echo "Usage: $0 file command [arguments]" 1>&2
    exit 1;;
esac

file="$1"
shift
new=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/ovrwr.$$.1
old=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/ovrwr.$$.2

trap "rm -f '$new' '$old' ; exit 1" 0 1 2 15

if "$@" >"$new"
then
    cp "$file" "$old"
    trap "" 1 2 15
    cp "$new" "$file"
    rm -f "$new" "$old"
    trap 0
    exit 0
else
    echo "$0: $1 failed - $file unchanged" 1>&2
    rm -f "$new" "$old"
    trap 0
    exit 1
fi
```

It's old code; I haven't modified it for almost a decade now, but I have used it quite a lot.  As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789885/more-elegant-method-of-sorting-a-file-after-the-first-x-lines/27790010#comment43990001_27790010) by [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy), it could do with some modernization if you're likely to face file names starting with dashes (because those could be mistaken for command-line options to `cp` or `mv`), and it should have a shebang line, etc.

It also shows trapping signals (though nowadays, I usually trap '`0 1 2 3 13 15`', equivalent to '`EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM`') and naming temporary files for preventing casual interference (using `$$` rather than `mktemp` — like I said, it is old code).

Comment: Could probably stand to add some `--`s to make `ow` correctly handle filenames starting with dashes rather than treating them as sets of options.

Comment: With a fresh version of gawk you can use `awk -i inplace`

Comment: How `{ print | "sort" }'` works if awk is printing one line at a time ? oO

Comment: @sputnick: All `print | "cmd"` operations with the same value for `"cmd"` go to the same output stream.  The output stream is closed when the `awk` script finishes, letting `sort` (in the real code) get on with sorting and generating its output.  The `awk` code waits for the `sort` to complete before finally exiting itself.  The behaviour is mandated by the POSIX definition of [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).

Comment: Wow, crafty Jonathan =)

Answer (score 2):

you can do a sort that skips some lines at the start of the file like this:

```
 { head -n 15 && sort; } < file > tempfile
```

it works because because head stops reading after 15 lines, so sort sees the rest of the file.

so to solve the full original problem.

```
{ head -n 15 && sort; } < file > tempfile && mv tempfile file
```

Comment: Using `;` rather than `&&` here means that the exit status of `head` is ignored, so if the attempt to read the header fails for some reason, we still proceed to write to the rest of the file -- making this operation potentially destructive. (Granted, it *shouldn't* happen that the `head` fails but the `sort` succeeds, but NFS can do strange things on unreliable networks).

Comment: G'deal. I'd also suggest using `{ head -n 15 && sort; }` rather than `(...)` for performance reasons -- no need for the overhead of a subshell. One might also make the implied `&& mv tempfile file` explicit.

Comment: The semicolon after the `sort` is actually mandatory when using a one-liner with curly braces for command grouping (if there were a line break between the `sort` and the `}` it would be fine without). Shell syntax is funny, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
 { head -n 15 file; tail -n+16 file | sort ; }
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that it exits with a failure (and without modifying the original file) if one of the processes in the pipeline fails, and doesn't handle overwriting the input file in-place.

Comment: ...which is my point, as the OP's question calls for doing so.